# Varchar to date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, date-format

I have `varchar` data in database table which stores date in `DD-MM-YYYY` format.

I want to select that `varchar` in `MM-DD-YYYY` format.

I'm using

```
select convert (varchar(30), (select CONVERT(datetime, '16-11-2011', 103)), 101)
```

It gives `11/16/2011`

Any simple query is possible for this?

Comment: @gbn No, I have to use a database which is designed by other who had declared the field as varchar if i change something the software using that database will give some error so. and I want MM-DD-YYYY format in front end it may be date or varchar.

Comment: I'm closing this as too basic for dba.se, which is for ["all advanced database-related topics"](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Comment: Why bother closing the question?  People have answered and voted for it.  I disagree that it is off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is string manipulation: nothing to do with datetimes

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(Whatever, 4,2) + '-' + LEFT(Whatever, 2) + '-' + RIGHT(Whatever, 4)
FROM
   SomeTable;
```

If you stored it as datetime, then you'd format it into whatever locale you wanted on the client. Then it'd be sortable and comparable too.